# Why does LayerNorm in pytorch have normalized_shape parameter. Why not just specify the dims along which normalization is to take place?

Tags: pytorch

[LayerNorm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LayerNorm.html) in pytorch has a parameter named `normalized_shape`.

> `normalized_shape`:If a single integer is used, it is treated as a singleton list, and this module will normalize over the last dimension which is expected to be of that specific size.

So ,it tells pytorch which dimensions to normalize across.

While computing mean or any other op in pytorch such an information is passed with just the dimension number that the aggregation is to take place across with -1 meaning the last dimension. LayerNorm cannot even be applied if you pass in the wrong number of elements. So, why this design choice?

Example:

```
from torch import nn

import torch

ln = nn.LayerNorm(3) #only 3 or (2,3) would be accepted
###ln = nn.LayerNorm(1) #fails with runtime error telling you the shape mismatch problem

ln(torch.randn(2,3))
```

Why is `nn.LayerNorm(across_how_many_last_dimensions)` not the signature of the function? What use case am I missing that this parameter choice is to serve?

Answer (score 1):

This bugged me too and I found the answer in source code (`init` function of `nn.LayerNorm`)

```
if self.elementwise_affine:
    self.weight = Parameter(torch.empty(self.normalized_shape, **factory_kwargs))
    if bias:
        self.bias = Parameter(torch.empty(self.normalized_shape, **factory_kwargs))
```

`normalized_shape` argument needs to be exact in order to initialize `weight` and `bias` parameters if `elemenetwise_affine` is `True` (which it is by default).

I am not too fond of this design choice but I have to admit it's better than figuring out the dimensions during the first `forward` call.